# "Unsupported type <Type>" error in Unity on System.Serialize class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class named PotionEffect. It needs System.Serializable, as I have to edit its parameters in editor and runtime. This error keeps popping up every time I edit a value (be it the enum, the int or the bool). It doesn't do anything (I can still run it) but I'd like to know where it comes from. Thanks in advance.

Exact error thrown:

```
Unsupported type PotionEffect
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList/Defaults:DrawElement (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEditor.SerializedProperty,object,bool,bool,bool,bool)
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList:DoListElements (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEngine.Rect)
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList:DoList (UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEngine.Rect)
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableListWrapper:Draw (UnityEngine.GUIContent,UnityEngine.Rect,UnityEngine.Rect,bool)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

It always comes alongside one like this:

`Unsupported type PotionEffect`

The class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Linq;

[Serializable]
public class PotionEffect
{
    public enum EffectTypes { none, stamina, strength, stun };
    public EffectTypes effect;
    public int duration;
    public bool started;

    public PotionEffect(EffectTypes e, int d)
    {
        this.duration = d;
        this.effect = e;
    }
    public PotionEffect(EffectTypes e)
    {
        this.duration = 15;
        this.effect = e;
    }
    public IEnumerator StartEffect()
    {
        if (started)
            yield break;
        started = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        effect = EffectTypes.none;
    }
}
```

Unity version: 2020.3.17f1
Visual Studio 2019
Windows 10

I tried moving this class to other files or to be within another class and nothing changes. Other posts seem to have different issues. Restarting the editor didn't fix it.

Lastly, I tried reattaching the component and it solved it, though I'm not sure how long this will last. I would also just like to have an explanation

Comment: Try to add a parameterless constructor.